# When installed globally, my node app looks in the global node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

I'm making an app to generate a component structure for a client project. The app needs to be run from the command line and so I've made it a published npm app that can be installed globally, however when I run the app, it's ignoring the directory I'm trying to run it from and instead just looking in it's own node_modules directory (I've tried this under nvm and regularly installed node)

I'm trying to set the project root using the following: `var projectRoot = path.dirname(require.main.filename)`

I've also tried by using `__dirname`, which also failed to work.

The specific problem I'm trying to solve (although this is only the first of a few, all of which seem to be caused by the app looking in the wrong place) is that the app needs to find a config file before it will run. I've included the example code for this below:

```
fs.stat(path.join(projectRoot, '/clarity.yml'), function (err, stat) {
  if (err === null) {
    console.log(chalk.green('clarity.yml detected!\nLoading your preferences...\n\n'))
    config = yml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync(path.join(projectRoot, '/clarity.yml'), 'utf8'))
    questionTime()
  } else if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
    console.error(chalk.red('clarity.yml not found. Please add one to the root of your project. A template can be found at https://git.io/v5Tt2 \nProcess aborted with errors'))
    process.exit(1)
  }
})
```

The most annoying part is that when I made this about a year ago, it worked without issue, however, I was running node v4.4.5 then and now I am using v8.0.0 (I've also tried it on v6.0.0 and v7.0.0 with the same result).

Comment: idk how about: `path.join(__dirname, 'clarity.yml')`?

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: I would do it like: console.log the path to see where node.js is looking and then check with some file explorer if the file is there.

Comment: .... "clarity.yml" is supposed to be in the current working directory? then just do `fs.stat('clarity.yml')`

Comment: Done that. I know where it's going. My problem is that I want to stop it going there. Instead of it going to ```/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/ctgen/``` I want it to go to the current directory that it is being run from. e.g. `~/projects/my-project`

Comment: read my third comment :) this should work then. If you really need the cwd use `process.cwd()`, but paths are relative to this anyway so i guess you don't need it.

Comment: Looks like that worked! Dunno why I didn't just think of that earlier. #stupidbrain.

Thanks, dude. :)